# UITableView is not showing any value

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have wired datasource and delegate but it is not showing any data in the table.M unable to find any mistake

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ReviewTableViewCell *cell = (ReviewTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    APIParsedForPhotoAndReviews *ele=(APIParsedForPhotoAndReviews *)[feedsForReview objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[ReviewTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.lblName.text=ele.strname;
    cell.lblReview.text=ele.strreview;
    cell.lblRating.text=ele.strrating;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you using CustomCell??

Comment: ya m using custom cell

Comment: Then you have to load its nib in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Are you using storyboard or xib?

Comment: xib ...and ya i forgot to register nib ..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to register the cell, before you use the reusable Cell.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
[tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```